# Inserting PHP Session Variables into MySQL Database

Tags: php, forms, session

I am having issues with my PHP code. I am trying to insert data into a mysql database using two session variables that I will need at a later time in the form. However whenever I submit the form I am returned with a "Unknown column in 'field list'" error.
The code is lengthy but you will likely need all of it to understand the issue.

```
    <?php
        session_start();
// Check for hazards and put them in an array if there is one selected
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
require ('../mysqli_connect.php'); //connect to the db

//Check for offender first name
if (empty($_POST['pris_firstname'])) {
$errors[] = 'You forgot to enter offender first name.';
    } else {
        $prisf=$_POST['pris_firstname'];
    }   

//Check for offender last name
if (empty($_POST['pris_lastname'])) {
$errors[] = 'You forgot to enter offender last name.';
    } else {
        $prisl=$_POST['pris_lastname'];
    }           

//Check for offender date of birth
$dob = ($_POST['pris_dateofbirth']);


//Check for offender phone number
if (empty($_POST['pris_phonenum'])) {
$errors[] = 'You forgot to enter offender Phone Number.';
    } else {
        $prisphone=trim($_POST['pris_phonenum']);
    }           

//Check for offender address
if (empty($_POST['pris_address'])) {
$errors[] = 'You forgot to enter offender Address.';
    } else {
        //$prisaddress=trim($_POST['pris_address']);
        foreach($_POST["pris_address"] as $value) { 
        $prisaddress .= $value . '\n'; 
    } 
    }   



//Check for offender next of kin first name
if (empty($_POST['pris_kinfirstname'])) {
$errors[] = 'You forgot to enter next of kin first name.';
    } else {
        $kinfirst=trim($_POST['pris_kinfirstname']);
    }   

//Check for offender next of kin last name
if (empty($_POST['pris_kinlastname'])) {
$errors[] = 'You forgot to enter next of kin last name.';
    } else {
        $kinlast=trim($_POST['pris_kinlastname']);
    }           

//Check for offender next of kin phone number
if (empty($_POST['pris_kinphone'])) {
$errors[] = 'You forgot to enter next of kin area code.';
    } else {
        $kinphone=trim($_POST['pris_kinphone']);
    }           

if (empty($_POST['pris_kinrelation'])) {
$errors[] = 'You forgot to enter next of kin relation.';
    } else {
        $kinrelation=trim($_POST['pris_kinrelation']);
    }

//Check for offender next of kin address
if (empty($_POST['pris_kinaddress'])) {
$errors[] = 'You forgot to enter next of kin street address.';
    } else  {
                foreach($_POST["pris_kinaddress"] as $value2) { 
                $kinaddress .= $value2 . '\n'; 
            } 
            }                   
if (empty($errors)) { //if everyhing is ok
$q = "INSERT INTO prisoner_profile (pris_status, 
                                    pris_firstname, 
                                    pris_lastname, 
                                    pris_dateofbirth, 
                                    pris_phonenum, 
                                    pris_address, 
                                    pris_kinfirstname, 
                                    pris_kinlastname, 
                                    pris_kinphone, 
                                    pris_kinaddress, 
                                    pris_kinrelation
                                    ) VALUES (
                                    '$status', 
                                               ".$_SESSION['pris_firstname'].",  ".$_SESSION['pris_lastname'].",
                                    '$dob', 
                                    '$prisphone', 
                                    '$prisaddress', 
                                    '$kinfirst', 
                                    '$kinlast', 
                                    '$kinphone', 
                                    '$kinaddress', 
                                    '$kinrelation'
                                    )"; 
$r = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $q); //Run the query.
```

Hope someone can help!

Comment: What unknown column is it listing?  Have you checked that all the columns in your query exist in the DB? Also, you need single quotes around where you insert the session values.  Finally, your code is very vulnerable to SQL injection. You should read up on how to resolve this using `mysqli`

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys! I am painfully new at this stuff and will give it all a try. The odd thing is that if I change the session variable back to regular variable the query runs with no errors. I will keep working away at it!

Comment: Also if I change the double quotes around the session variables to single the page is a white screen of death

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is pretty much self-explanatory, it means that you have got a column name wrong in your database. I recomend you echo out the error for your query just for this case as:

`$r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q) or die (mysqli_error());`

Comment: That is what would seem to be the issue. However the "field" that it tells me is incorrect shows up as whatever I type into the form for taht variable. Also, the code work if I use only number in the First Name and Last Name fields. The actual field in my database ate both VARCHAR(30).

Comment: I figured it out, thanks so much to everyone! It was indeed linked to a typo, however I also changed the ".$_SESSION['pris_firstname']." to '$_SESSION[pris_firstname]' now it works perfectly! I will look into the sql injection problems!

Answer (score 2):

One of the columns that are listed in your `INSERT` statement does not actually exist in the `prisoner_profile`. Check your table schema.

Answer (score 1):

The one obvious issue I can see here is that you haven't handled the escape characters in your query, and you have used a few `\n` characters in your code.

Use `mysqli_real_escape_string` to handle that when inputting the data to the database.

Something like

```
$q = mysqli_real_escape_string($q);
```